# Rails + RSpec - Integration Testing (Recommendations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, rspec, capybara, vue-router

I have a Vue app with a rails backend and I want to do some front-end/integration testing. I'm currently using `vue-router` and `turbolinks` on the front-end and `RSpec` for unit testing.

I tried using `Capybara` but `puma` always give me a routing error when a link is clicked and trying to get a route instead of having the vue router handle rendering the component. With the help of others, we suspect it's either that vue router is not loaded properly or turbolinks is interfering in some way. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to configure Capybara for this situation?

Or does anyone have recommendations on other tools/libraries that I can use for testing?

Comment: reccomendations for tools / libs are offtopic for SO